# Order an specific ID by date - Get out just one (queue system)

Tags: php, mysql, date, queue

Okey, I need to order an specific ID by date.

Let's say that I have:

Id 50 = 2015-01-22 14.00

Id 51 = 2015-01-23 14.00

I need to order this and get out just one with WHERE? (I guess)

So If I have $_GET['51'] I need to know which place it has. In this case: Number 2

And I will also need an list of it all, so:

Number 1 = Id 50 = 2015-01-22 14.00

Number 2 = Id 51 = 2015-01-23 14.00

So basic, I want to know how to change the date to numbers and order them by the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select count(*) as therank
from table t
where t.date <= (select t2.date from table t2 where t2.id = 51);
```

It returns the rank of id = 51, based on the date.

Comment: @Johan . . . The query returns the rank.

Comment: I need to order by "status = accepted" and "paid = 1" also, do you know how to do that? So it will be right in the queue!

Comment: This doesn't work:

select count(*) from orders t where t.date <= (select t2.date from orders t2 where t2.id = '51' AND t2.status = 'accepted')

Comment: @Johan . . . I think you need to repeat the conditions in both the inner and outer query to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  @i:=@i+1 nr_crt, 
        id 
FROM    table,
        (SELECT @i:= 0) AS i
        ORDER BY date DESC;